# Unable to call different function every time while tapping NFC card

Tags: android, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, nfc

In my app, i have two ionic controllers. First login controller, when tapping NFC card , it will verify the card number and login. Second Dashboard controller, when tapping new NFC card, it will verify the card number and get value from api. But when i tap second NFC card, first controller is also called. I am using 'addTagDiscoveredListener' for read the NFC card. Help me to call different function every time while tapping NFC card. I have this code in both controllers,

```
var nfcid = nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(onNfc, win, fail);
```

Comment: I don't know nfc, but from the name of the function `add....Listener()` I'd be looking for something like `remove...Listener()` once you've done with the login stage.

Comment: I have added 'removeTagDiscoveredListener' also, but still same issues